# DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8') not working when using google maps

Tags: php, google-maps, domdocument

I am trying to make a map marker using this demo link

```
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml.html
```

but, i get fatal error here on the line

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); // Creates the root KML element and appends it to the root document. 
$node = $dom->createElementNS('http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1', 'kml');
$parNode = $dom->appendChild($node);
```

The script doesn't seems to work 
when i use NS, it tries to save the document and when i remove NS, i get the error as

**( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error' in C:\wamp\www\googlemap\phpsql_genkml.php on line 33
( ! ) DOMException: Invalid Character Error in C:\wamp\www\googlemap\phpsql_genkml.php on line 33
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0012  412392  {main}( )   ..\phpsql_genkml.php:0
2   0.0066  422136  DOMDocument->createElement( )   ..\phpsql_genkml.php:33**

Comment: Please attach the fatal error message

Comment: attach to your question, **NOT** in comment, and that's the PHP code, **NOT** PHP error message

Comment: What is on line 33 in phpsql_genkml.php? BTW, I'm using `$kml = $dom->createElementNS('http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2', 'kml');` to create the root-element; That is the namespace used by Google in [their documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#kml), but I don't think, your error has to do with the namespace…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove the NS in createElementNS.
When you do it createElement tries to create an element with the tagName "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1"(I think I don't need to explain what invalid characters are there). The tagtName has to be **kml**

How do you use this generated KML in Google-Maps, who tries to save anything?

Comment: On how to use KML: see the [OpenLayers-examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html) (I use OpenLayers, because it provides an easy method for switching between map-services, e.g. Open Street Map, Google Maps or Bing Maps)

Comment: I know how to use it, I like to know how the OP uses it(using it with google-maps usually didn't force any download/save as)